# I need to delete lines when pattern match

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have file on a Linux system, `aa.text`, which contains the lines below:

```
$ cat aa.text
I am a user
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [PCRMR2S]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:51 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:51 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:51 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:51 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:52 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:54 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:54 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:55 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:56 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:56 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:56 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:56 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:58:03 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
username is valid
Fri Feb 09 23:58:04 2024
```

I want to get output like:

```
i am a user
username is valid 
Fri Feb 09 23:58:04 2024
```

I tried:

```
sed -e '/ORA-1653/,+1 d' aa
```

which gives me:

```
i am a user
Fri Feb 09 23:57:51 2024
Fri Feb 09 23:57:51 2024
Fri Feb 09 23:57:51 2024
Fri Feb 09 23:57:52 2024
Fri Feb 09 23:57:54 2024
Fri Feb 09 23:57:55 2024
Fri Feb 09 23:57:56 2024
username is valid
Fri Feb 09 23:58:04 2024
```

but I need

```
i am a user
username is valid 
Fri Feb 09 23:58:04 2024
```

How can I do this?

The requirement is not only print the timestamp on last (line). Requirement is IF the match word (e.g. `ORA-1653`) found AND the subsequent next line is timestamp then delete both the rows, but if the match word is not found and the subsequent next line is timestamp then it should not delete that timestamp.

Comment: So how can we know what lines you want? Should we just print all lines matching `user`? Should we print the first and last line of the file? And why is the `I` in `I am a user` changed to `i` in the output? Is that a typo or do you need to change the case?

Comment: Please explain how we can know what lines to keep. Explain in words. What algorithm should we follow here? Do you want the first and las two lines of the file? Do you only want the specific date? How can we know if a line should be kept or not?

Comment: Are you saying the `ORA-1653` line sometimes comes out as a couplet with a Timestamp following, and you'd like that Timestamp removed if (and-only-if) it immediately follows the `ORA-1653` line? Thx.

Comment: VTC seriously needs details

Answer (score 1):

This produces the output you expect from the input you provided:

```
$ head -n 1 file; tail -n 2 file
I am a user
username is valid
Fri Feb 09 23:58:04 2024
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to tell us your requirements for selecting the 3 lines to be output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-v` key for `grep`. Without it, the `grep` will print rows which have the pattern, with `-v`, `grep` prints rows without such pattern.

Since you have two types of rows to ignore, you need two patterns for `grep` to search. Mark them with `-e`.

So you can try this:

```
grep -v -e "ORA-1653" -e "Fri Feb" aa.text
```

Comment: That gives the same wrong output as the OP's `sed` command.

Comment: it should not delete the line showing time ..... it should delete time only when ora-1653 matched and if the time showing line is next line of the matched word ..... if line does not contain grep word and subsequently next line is timestamp line then it should not delete that line

Comment: Unless you explain what you need, @ANW, we can't help you. White Owl tried, but since we don't know what you need, all we can do is guess.

Comment: I have edited the requirement now

Comment: @ANW no, you haven't. You still haven't explained how we can know what lines to keep and what lines to discard. Is it based on line number? On a pattern? What pattern? You need to explain what you want us to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- there are 3 different line formats ...
- *format #1*: line starts with `ORA`
- *format #2*: line contains a date/time stamp of the format `Day Mon dd hh:mm:ss yyyy`
- *format #3*: anything that does not match *format #1* or *format #2*
- objective is to ...
- ignore lines with *format #1*
- print last line with *format #2*
- print all ines with *format #3*

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN    { regex = "[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]" }    # hh:mm:ss

/^ORA/   {                next }                           # format #1

NF==5 &&
$4~regex { last_dt = $0 ; next }                           # format #2

1                                                          # format #3 (ie, everything else)

END      { print last_dt }
' aa.txt
```

This generates:

```
I am a user
username is valid
Fri Feb 09 23:58:04 2024
```

Comment: the requirement is not only print the timestamp on last ....Requirement is if the match word found and the subsequent next line is timestamp then delete both the rows but if the match word is not found and the subsequent next line is timestamp then it should not delete that timestamp .... as the given file is just an example .... since the original file is 6gb so cannot copy the entire file

Comment: I am a user
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [PCRMR2S]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:51 2024
username is anw
Fri Feb 09 23:57:54 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:56 2024
Fri Feb 09 23:57:56 2024
i love stackexchange
Fri Feb 09 23:57:54 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
username is valid

Expected output:
I am a user
username is anw
Fri Feb 09 23:57:54 2024
i love stackexchange
Fri Feb 09 23:57:54 2024
username is valid

Comment: @ANW as others have already commented, the question is lacking in details for us to understand what it is you want; adding details in comments does not help since not everyone is going to peruse comments in an attempt to understand the bigger picture; ***update the question*** with the additional details; you don't need to provide a 6GB file but you do need to provide enough sample data to adequately demonstrate your data

Comment: you should be able to provide 15-20 lines of data that includes lines that match your requirement (ORA-1653) as well as lines that do not match your requirement (ORA-some_other_number); you should be able to *describe* in text your requirements

Comment: @ANW how on earth were we supposed to _guess_ those requirements? If you don't tell us IN THE QUESTION we cannot hope to know

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @day-of-week = <Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat>;  \
            for slurp() { 
                put S:g/ ^^ ORA \- 1653 \: \h .+? $$ [\n ^^ @day-of-week .+? $$]? \n // 
            };  file
```

#OR

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @day-of-week = <Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat>;  \
            S:g/^^ ORA \- 1653 \: \h .+? $$ [\n ^^ @day-of-week .+? $$]? \n //.put for slurp;'  file
```

Above is an answer written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. The file is `slurp`ed in (read into memory all at once), and the two target lines are described in the recognition domain of Raku's `S///` "big-S" substitution operator (made global with the `S:g///` named-parameter). The second line `[\n ^^ Fri .+? $$]?` is made optional with the `?` enumerator. In the replacement half is nothing, deleting the recognized textual sequence.

Sample Input:

```
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [PCRMR2S]
I am a user
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [PCRMR2S]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:51 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:51 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:51 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:51 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:52 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:54 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:54 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:55 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:56 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:56 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:56 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:57:56 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
Fri Feb 09 23:58:03 2024
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
ORA-1653: unable to extend table SYS.AUD$ by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM [ABCD]
username is valid
Fri Feb 09 23:58:04 2024
```

Sample Output:

```
I am a user
username is valid
Fri Feb 09 23:58:04 2024
```

*There does appear to be a `\n` newline inserted at the end of the "Sample Output" above. If this is a problem, then it can be solved by interposing a call to the `.trim-trailing` routine between `S:g///` and the final `.put`.*

---

Above works if you have memory to `slurp` the file in all-at-once. If size is an issue, the answer below reads the input_file linewise. It uses Raku's *Ternary* operator (which is spelled somewhat differently from Perl): **Test** `??` **True** `!!` **False**.

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @day-of-week = <Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat>; my $flag = 0; \
            for lines() { / ^ ORA \- 1653 \: \h .+ $ /          \
                ?? ( $flag=1 andthen next )                     \
                !! ( $flag == 1 and / ^ @day-of-week .+ $ /)    \
                    ?? ( $flag=0 andthen next )                 \
                    !! ( .put andthen $flag=0 ) };'   file
I am a user
username is valid
Fri Feb 09 23:58:04 2024
```

https://docs.raku.org/routine/slurp
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#S///_non-destructive_substitution
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_??_!!
https://raku.org